# Domain name redirecting to IP address on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

[image: Route 53 page]I have been trying to host a wordpress instance on AWS which worked marvelously. I have bought and set a domain name. Set the Route53 DNS but each time i type the domain name (), it opens the site but with the IP address on the address bar instead on the site name(http://54.XX.XX.XXX.xip.io/wp-signup.php?new=asimilas.com)

I have tried to look into many websites about wordpress and AWS with no change
All the A records have the same IP

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. You just need to change your **WordPress' Home url and Site url** to your domain name. For eg:  http://www.asimilas.com and save the settings. The home url and site url can be found under the **General Settings** tab.
 Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is i can't locate the **Home URL** and **Site URL**. It seems they are disabled and i can't find no way to get them

Comment: Also, I face this issue **without wordpress**

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the Wordpress Address URL and Site Address URL is found under the Settings tab. If not, then try updating the home URL and site URL fields which are in the **wp_options** table from the database. 
**Syntax:**

```
>  select * from wp_options where option_name like 'home%'; 
>  update wp_options set option_value = 'http://asimilas.com' where option_name = 'home';                                                                            
>  select * from wp_options where option_name like 'site%';
>  update wp_options set option_value = 'http://asimilas.com' where option_name = 'siteurl';
```